# Koordinate undeclared error

Tags: iphone, coordinates

In my code I want to create coordinates values from array:

```
for(int i=1; i<[appDelegate.latitudeArray count]; i++) {


           Koordinate *coord = [[Koordinate alloc] init];
           coord.latitude = [[appDelegate.latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
           coord.longtitude = [[appDelegate.longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
}
```

But i am getting error as Koordinate undeclared. I have also added CoreLocation Framework.

Comment: Unrelated but why is the loop starting from 1 (arrays start at index 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is no class named `Koordinate`, there is only `CLLocationCoordinate2D` which is a struct

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordiante;
coordiante.latitude =[[appDelegate.latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
coord.longtitude = [[appDelegate.longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
```